# c# Como puedo recorrer un data set y mostrar sus valores?

Tags: c#

tengo un metodo que me devuelve un dataset con : Art, numero, interno, color..
Lo que yo quiero es hacer otro metodo, que me recorra ese mismo dataset y mostrar su valores!

Pero no entiendo como se hace para recorrerlo, se que es con un foreach pero no me sale! gracias por las respuestas

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult ObtengoDatosConInterno(string NombreSeccion, string NombreCategoria, string NombreEstilo, string NombreMarca, int NumTalle)
        {
            try
            {
                var datosCInterno = Metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno(Casa(), NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle);
                return Ok(datosCInterno);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(ex.Message) });
            }
        }
//En metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno ahi tengo mi consulta normal que me trae los datos de sql
//yo lo que quiero es hacer otro metodo, que me recorra ese data set!
//Lo empeze asi

  [HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult RecorroDS(string NombreSeccion, string NombreCategoria, string NombreEstilo, string NombreMarca, int NumTalle)
        {
            try
            {
                var datosCInterno = Metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno(Casa(), NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle);
                foreach (DataSet ds in datosCInterno[0].Rows) {
                //me queda mal el foreach, no se bien que recorrer
                //aca adentro tendria que llamar a los datos que me devuelve el otro metodo, que son                    Articulo, Fabricante , color e interon
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError) { Content = new StringContent(ex.Message) });
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El `DataSet` contiene `DataTable` y éste contiene `DataRows` por lo que deberías modificar tu `foreach` y ponerle que lo que vas a recorrer son `DataRows` y no `DataSet`, te muestro el código suponiendo que sólo tienes 1 `DataTable` en el `DataSet` (posición 0):

```
DataSet datosCInterno = Metodos.MisMetodos.CargoDatosConInterno(Casa(), NombreSeccion, NombreCategoria, NombreEstilo, NombreMarca, NumTalle);
foreach (DataRow dr in datosCInterno.Tables[0].Rows) 
{
    //Muestras los valores obteniendolos con el Índice o el Nombre de la columna, 
    //   de la siguiente manera:
    string valor = dr["NombreColumna"].ToString();
    string valor2 = dr[0].ToString();
}
```

Comment: Intente con esto que me decis y me aparece un error que dice : No se puede aplicar la indizacion [] a una expresion de tipo DataSet!....
Yo habia probado con

 ------------DataSet datos = datosCInterno;
                foreach (DataSet ds in datos.Tables[0].Rows) { -- -----esto esta bien?

Comment: @tato8vio He modificado la respuesta, añadiendo `datosCInterno.Tables[0]` que me habia dejado

Comment: Ahivaa bien ahi me quedo si! muchas gracias! Despues como seria para castearlo? osea, yo quiero obtener de ahi, el fabricante, el articulo, la descripcion y el color (Me lo devuelve la consulta a la cual llamo al metodo)

Comment: @tato8vio Entonces deberias de recojer los datos con `dr[NombreColumna_o_índice]`

Comment: @tato8vio Recuerda marcar la respuesta que te ha sido de ayuda. Si tienes cualquier otra pregunta siempre puedes postear una nueva en la red para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Muchas gracias me ha servido de mucho!